# Scala - List.isDefinedAt() behaves strange

Tags: list, scala

As far as I know, the `isDefinedAt` method should work like types `contains` method. But strangely enough, it behaves differently - it does not check elements for repeated occurence.

```
val randomizer = new Random

def next(acc: List[Int], n: Int): List[Int] = {
   if(n > 0) {
      val r = randomizer.nextInt(15)
      println("generating, r=" + r + " is defined=" + acc.isDefinedAt(r))
      if(!acc.isDefinedAt(r)) next(r :: acc, n - 1) // check for NO coincidence
      else next(acc, n)
   } else acc
}

println("indices = " + next(List[Int](), 6))
```

Ofcourse, I can use Sets for that instead of lists, but nevertheless, why does it act like this?

The output that I get is like

```
generating, r=8 is defined=false
generating, r=13 is defined=false
generating, r=2 is defined=false
generating, r=8 is defined=false
generating, r=9 is defined=false
generating, r=3 is defined=true
generating, r=2 is defined=true
generating, r=7 is defined=false

indices = List(7, 9, 8, 2, 13, 8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `isDefinedAt` does is tell you if a function does not accept an argument. That is, if `isDefinedAt` returns `false`, then you know the function doesn't cover that value. For `true`, it may cover the value or throw an exception.

In the specific case of `List` (and all `Seq`), `isDefinedAt(i)` will return true if `0 <= i < list.size`, and false otherwise, and `list(i)` will only throw an exception if `isDefinedAt(i)` returns false.

Anyway, let's try it out:

```
scala> val list = List("a", "b", "c")
list: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> list.isDefinedAt(0)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> list(0)
res1: String = a


scala> list.isDefinedAt(-1)
res3: Boolean = false

scala> list(-1)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: -1


scala> list.isDefinedAt(2)
res5: Boolean = true

scala> list(2)
res6: String = c
```

Comment: All answers are equally good, thanks! A hard choice ). I mark this one which has the most explicit example...

Answer (score 7):

The `isDefineAt` method tells you whether a given partial function is defined for a given argument, i.e. whether it will give you a value when you call it with the given argument.

Since Lists are treated as partial functions from their indices to their values, `isDefinedAt` will tell you whether a given index is valid for a List. It will not tell you whether a given value is contained in the list, that's what `contains` is for.

Note that despite the fact that you called your list `indices`, 7, 9, 8, 2, 13 and 8 are the *values* of that list. The indices of that list are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstand the mean of `isDefindAt`, it is not work as `contains`.
As the docs says:

> def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean
>
> Tests whether this list contains given index.
>
> returns
>
> ```
> true if this list contains an element at position idx, false otherwise.
> ```

So `isDefinedAt(x)` equals with `0<= x && x< list.size`